# Why are files in the map 'Desktop' not shown on the desktop?

Tags: debian, gnome3, desktop

As far as my memory goes, the map 'Desktop' contains the files which are shown on your desktop. However, my desktop is empty, while having files present in the map.

Yes, I mostly prefer an empty desktop, but it seems strange to me to be *unable* having anything on the desktop. And sometimes it just comes in handy to have certain files close.

So, my question is: How to enable having files on my desktop again?

I am using Debian Wheezy with Gnome 3.

Edit: I am not interested in installing different desktop environments, just in a solution to get this working in Gnome3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it seems I just didn't search at all places. 
In Advanced Settings, under the tab Desktop, there is the option 'Have file manager handle the desktop'. 
In case this is on, the file manager handles the desktop, and with that, the files on the desktop, enabling one to put files onto it. 
When this is off, as I had it, this is not possible, and one can panic for quite a long time about it.

Comment: Where is the Advanced Settings Option?

Comment: @Archer You have to install GNOME Tweaks from the Software store.

Answer (score 4):

Open Tweak tool from applications, on Tweak tool select desktop and make 'icons on desktop' to "ON", Thats all

Answer (score -1):

Empty desktop is show when desktop is somehow disabled. Try installing another desktop environment like LXDE, it will surely show your files.